# Can a push notification skip the notification center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to send a push notification to my users without entering the notification center? I want to display a popup that will die after confirm or cancel. 
I know it was possible in ios 4 and was replaced by the Notification Center but I have to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no way** for you as a developer. This can be set in *Settings* for each application:

[image]

Comment: Even if I send the notification with badge=0 ?

Comment: Badge zero removes badge number from app's icon. It has nothing to do with alert style.

Comment: I agree , yet, to remove the notification from the NC I need to use something like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];` Kinda confusing